# MySQL puzzle: How to combine result in Loop?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So far I have tried using 
 `CREATE VIEW <view_table_name>` and 
 
`CREATE TABLE <table_name>` and 
 `CREATE TEMPORARY <temporary_table_name>`
and this methods are taking so much time because I have to `(step 1) create a table` and `(step 2) insert a data`. Then `(step 3) select the created table`. Finally, `(step 4) drop the table`.

**This is my procedure:** (My program doesn't look make any sense, I mean why am I doing this. The answer to your confusion is, this is just a part of my large code and I made it this way so that it may look simple.)

```
BEGIN
    -- Main loop variables
    DECLARE col_Name varchar(255);
    DECLARE col_Description varchar(255);

    -- Main Loop
    Block2: BEGIN
        DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE statement CURSOR FOR SELECT `name`, `description` FROM `rules`;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

        OPEN statement;
            REPEAT
                MainLoop: LOOP
                    FETCH statement INTO col_Name, col_Description;

                    IF done THEN
                        LEAVE MainLoop;
                    END IF;

                    SELECT col_Name AS `Name`, col_Description AS `Description`;

                END LOOP MainLoop;

            UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        CLOSE statement;
    END Block2;
    -- End of Main Loop
END
```

**The result is:** 
[image]

**The problem:** 
The result is separate. How do I combine this result into one table?

Comment: The cursor and loop seems to server no purpose why not just SELECT `name`, `description` FROM `rules`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a temporary table at the beginning ,populate data into temp table and then access it after loop ends

```
BEGIN
        -- Main loop variables
        DECLARE col_Name varchar(255);
        DECLARE col_Description varchar(255);
        create temporary table yourtable (name varchar(50),description varchar(50));

        -- Main Loop
        Block2: BEGIN
            DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
            DECLARE statement CURSOR FOR SELECT `name`, `description` FROM `rules`;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

            OPEN statement;
                REPEAT
                    MainLoop: LOOP
                        FETCH statement INTO col_Name, col_Description;

                        IF done THEN
                            LEAVE MainLoop;
                        END IF;
                        insert into yourtable(name,description)
 values (col_Name, col_Description)


                    END LOOP MainLoop;

                UNTIL done END REPEAT;
            CLOSE statement;
        select * from yourtable
        END Block2;
        -- End of Main Loop
    END
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer.

Comment: What do you think about table and view? They are of the same method right? Which do you think is the fastest?

Comment: if you just want to show the result in table then why use table and view?Temporary table can be dropped after its usage,Also accept the answer if it is correct

Comment: I put in my description that I have already tried that method. Using temporary. I am still looking for better answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think things can be easier.

you don't have to use a cursor, you just need to create an empty table in your procedure, and input the result from your query.

like below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `temp`(val int)

BEGIN

DECLARE yourval datatype()
-- declare as many as you need.---

set @beginning = 0
set @ending = val
-- how many time do you need to repeat your code?

---CREATE AN EMPTY TABLE HERE---

while @beginning < @ending do
insert table TableCreatedAbove 

---YOUR QUERY---
---YOU MAY NEED TO DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR DECLARED VARIABLE---

set @beginning = @beginning + 1;

end while;
commit;
END
```

when you need to use your combined table, just

```
select * from TableCreatedAbove
```

maybe you already solved your problem in somewhere else, but here is my answer.